# How to change the order of IF statments based on a variable (from server)

Tags: java, android

Sorry if it's a noob question but I am just starting learning coding from zero.
Is there a more concise way to change the order of some IF statement based on a variable?

Of course I could do something like below code but I was wondering if there was a way to obtain a similar result in a more simple way instead of having to write every single order combination.
Sorry again if I the question is stupid.

```
if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(KEY) equals 1) {
        if (XXX_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            XXX_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
        if (YYY_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            YYY_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
        if (ZZZ_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            ZZZ_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
    } else if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(KEY) equals 2) {
        if (XXX_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            XXX_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
        if (ZZZ_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            ZZZ_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
        if (YYY_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            YYY_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
    } else if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(KEY) equals 3) {
        if (ZZZ_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            ZZZ_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
        if (XXX_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            XXX_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
        if (YYY_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            YYY_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
    } else if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(KEY) equals 4) {
        if (ZZZ_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            ZZZ_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
        if (YYY_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            YYY_Start.display();
            return true;
        }
        if (XXX_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            XXX_Start.display();
            return true;
        }   
    } else if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(KEY) equals 5) {
        if (YYY_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            YYY_Start.display();
            return true;
        }   
        if (XXX_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            XXX_Start.display();
            return true;
        }   
        if (ZZZ_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            ZZZ_Start.display();
            return true;
        }           
    } else if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(KEY) equals 6) {
        if (YYY_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            YYY_Start.display();
            return true;
        }   
        if (ZZZ_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            ZZZ_Start.display();
            return true;
        }   
        if (XXX_Start_Status.isLoaded()) {
            XXX_Start.display();
            return true;
        }                   
    }
```

Comment: Well first of all, `mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getBoolean(KEY)` returns a boolean, true or false. Not sure why you're comparing it to an integer. Also, you need `==` instead of `=` for comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577891/why-does-java-require-a-double-equals-sign

Comment: Apart from that, you should determine if the code that replaces `//do something` can be somehow more generalized, otherwise you'll basically be stuck with a bunch of `if` or `switch` statements

Comment: you can use `switch case` for `integer` numbers . and called `switch case `method from your three conditions

Comment: Tried to edit the code, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: now, you are comparing strings with integers, which is also not correct. Moreover, if it's really strings you need to use `equals` instead of `==`. I suggest you start with the basics and work through a good tutorial.